# How to START - STOP the image download process using ASIHttpRequest in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, asynchronous, asihttprequest

I have XML file parsing and it's image downloading from the server in my app.

I want parsing of each XML file and it's image downloading as a separate task/process.

User can be able to play - pause (start - stop using buttons) downloading of particular XML file's image in between.

So for that i need to detect complete (with count of images downloaded of that XML file) and failed status of each task (i.e XML parsing with it's image downloading).

I have searched a lot for this but could not find the solution.

I have gone through [This Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues) and also to [ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#creating_an_asynchronous_request) tutorial, but could not get any proper way to achieve this task.

How can i do this?

Please help me...

Thanks..

Comment: are you getting the image urls in XML?

Comment: every start button click images wants to be download from web ah

Comment: As far as I understand your problem, it's less a question of the correct network library, but rather a question how to solve asynchronous problems. Thus, forget tutorials about network libraries, the answer is not there. However, it would help if you could rephrase your question, so that it becomes parseable without grammar and syntax errors. This is essential to fully understand your problem ;)

Comment: @AashishJoshi yes i am getting images url from xml parsing.

Comment: @iDev yes. I am using collectionview and on didSelect of each cell, starts - stops the xml parsing and images downloading.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper oh. thanks for your suggestion. but than what should i do?

Comment: The best way i guess parse your xml and get the ulr save into coredata  or plist and the download and pause there status

Comment: @AashishJoshi ok. but user can click on multiple collection view cell to download images than in that case how can i detect which xml file is parsing and of which xml file's images are downloading???

Comment: you got a collection view and every collection view call xml? hmm use the index and use archive object of dictionary which will have the array of images and current downloaded index, simply a array of dictionary objects with status and image array will do for you

Comment: @AashishJoshi thanks a lot for your help and reply. Can you please provide sample code for this?? so that i can easily understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand your problem, but as far as I understand:

You seem to have one (or multiple?) XML files. Within the XML files there is one (or more?) URLs which are images which shall be downloaded from a server.

In this case I would suggest to parse *all* the XMLs and put all URLs in an NSMutableArray say, "imageURLs".

Once that is finished, which should be quick, you start downloading the images whose URL is in the array.

Whenever a download is complete, you remove the URL form the array.

A quick and dirty solution may look as follows:

Suppose, you have a wrapper method which loads one image:

```
typedef void(^completion_t)(id image, NSError* error);

- (void) loadImageWithURL:(NSURL*)url completion:(completion_t)completionHandler;
```

This asynchronous method is implemented using your favorite network library.

We also need an asynchronous helper method (or function) which sequentially invokes the asynchronous download tasks:

```
- (void) loadImagesWithURLs:(NSMutableArray*)urls completion:(completion_t)completionHandler
{
    if (self.isCancelled) {
        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(nil, [self newCancelError]);
        }
        return;
    }
    if ([urls count] > 0) {
        NSURL* urls = [urls firstObject];
        [urls removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [self loadImageWithURL:url completion:^(id image, NSError*error){
            dispatch_async(self.sync_queue, ^{
                if (image == nil) {
                    [self.failedURLs addObject:url];
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                }
                else {
                    [self.images addObject:image];
                }
                [self loadImagesWithURLs:urls completion:completionHander];
            });
        }];
    }
    else {
        // finished
        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(@"Downloads complete", nil);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: the method above looks like as if it were a recursive method call, since it will invoke itself. But actually, it is NOT. The method will invoke itself, but this happens from within the *completion handler* , and when this happens, the method already returned.

What we have here instead, is an *Asynchronous Loop*.

At every iteration, the method checks for the cancellation state, and returns immediately if it has been cancelled (or stopped).

The "loop" can be stopped by setting property "isCancelled" to YES. One can resume the loop by simple re-invoking the method with the array `urls` which contains the remaining URLs to be downloaded.

What's not shown here, is how one can accomplish to cancel the request.

The method also demonstrates how to concurrently access shared resources, namely a property `failedURLs` and a property `images`. Thus, there is a *serial* queue which is utilized to synchronize shared access to these arrays. Purposefully, this is just the main queue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i have UICollectionView and  start - stop of xml parsing and image downloading is on cell's didSelect . so i can not have all xml parsing at once